# Bugzilla with SSL

Tags: ssl, bugzilla

I have an install of Bugzilla I'm trying to implement SSL on.

When I go into the parameters screen and edit SSLBASE adding in the full url:

> https://foo.com/bugzilla/

the editparams.cgi times out on loading and I have the following error in the apache log

> [Tue Mar 30 19:29:39 2010] [error] [client xxx.xx.xx.xx ] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed, referer: http://foo.com/bugzilla/editparams.cgi

On install I also received this error:

> WARNING: You need to set the max_allowed_packet parameter in your MySQL
>   configuration to at least 3276750. Currently it is set to 3275776.
>   You can set this parameter in the [mysqld] section of your MySQL
>   configuration file.

How can I force this to work? Editing other parameters (eg urlbase) work fine. The SSL site is setup and direct requests to it eg https://foo.com/bugzilla work correctly.

Any ideas?

Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems fairly clear-cut to me.  Have you tried increasing your MySQL setting for `max_allowed_packet`?

Comment: seems obvious but was certain that I tried arbitrary large values and now it's started working.

Answer (score 0):

need few change of settings. Goto C:\mysql\bin\my.ini and set the max_allowed_packet setting to 4M. Underneath that, add the following line, mostly max_allowed_packet line not avialble in my.ini file, so add the following lines.

max_allowed_packet = 4M
ft_min_word_len = 2

now the above problem,wont occur